# Como remover um Elemento de um XML com Python?

Tags: python, xml

O caso é que tenho um arquivo produzido por um Garmin (aparelho GPS para exercício físico) e quero remover todos os campos referentes ao batimento cardíaco para passar o arquivo a um atleta que fez o exercício comigo. O arquivo está no formato GPX e é mais ou menos assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx version="1.1" ...>
  <metadata>...</metadata>
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lon="00" lat="00">
        <ele>000</ele>
        <time>2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
            <gpxtpx:hr>99</gpxtpx:hr>
          </gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
      ....
      <trkpt ...>
        ...
        <extensions>
          ...
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

O sistema basicamente gera um elemento `<trkpt>` a cada leitura (geográfica + fisiológica + outros aparelhos). Eu preciso remover todas as instâncias do elemento `<extensions>` dentro dos `<trkpt>` (ou seja, todo o conteúdo do mesmo). Eu tentei utilizando a biblioteca `ElementTree` com o seguinte código:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('input.gpx')
root = tree.getroot()
for ext in root[1][2].iter('{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}trkpt'):
  ext = trkpt.find('{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}extensions')
  root.remove(ext)
tree.write('output.gpx')
```

O código até remove os elementos, mas eu não gostei de 3 coisas aqui:

A primeira é que a biblioteca adiciona as URLs dos esquemas de XML aos nomes dos elementos. Perdi um bom tempo sem entender porquê meu algoritmo não encontrava os elementos...

A segunda é esse `root[1][2]` para ter um apontador para o pai dos elementos que quero remover. Eu conseguiria ter acesso aos elementos diretamente invocando `root.iter('{...}extensions')`.

E por fim, a questão mais séria é que ao escrever o resultado no arquivo percebi que a biblioteca renomeia as tags quebra o formato original. O resultado ficou assim:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:gpx ...>
  <ns0:metadata>...</ns0:metadata>
  <ns0:trk>...</ns0:trk>
</ns0:gpx>
```

Como não tenho experiência com esta biblioteca talvez esteja faltando alguma configuração que não vi na minha leitura superficial [da documentação](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Estou buscando então uma solução para meu problema com esta ou outra biblioteca.

Comment: É necessário ser em Python? É possível fazer isso com sed: sed '/<extensions>/,/<\/extensions>/d' input.gpx

Comment: Agradeço a dica Francisco. Eu já inclusive resolvi usando algo muito parecido dentro do Vim, mas estou tentando melhor meu pythonês. []

Comment: Ah, certo. É que você disse que era só para passar um arquivo para um amigo, achei que só queria uma solução rápida. :)

Comment: To sem tempo de escrever um exemplo agora, por isso vou comentar e não criar uma resposta. Mas da uma olhada na lib [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), muito usada para esse tipo de script.

Comment: Valeu @thiago-silva. Usei sua recomendação e postei uma resposta aqui. Muito legal a BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segui a dica deixada nos comentários da pergunta e resolvi o problema usando a biblioteca [BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (obrigado @thiago-silva)

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('input.gpx'), 'xml')
for ext in soup.find_all('extensions'):
  removed = ext.extract()

output = open('output.gpx','w')
output.write(soup.prettify())
output.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo o uso da biblioteca [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) pela performance e simplicidade da mesma:

```phyton
from lxml import etree

gpx = etree.parse(open('input.gpx'))

for node in gpx.xpath('//trkpt/extensions'):
    node.getparent().remove(node)

gpx.write(open('output.gpx', 'w'))
```

Usei o XPath para simplificar as coisas.

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais fácil de mexer com XML que eu achei ate hoje foi usando `xmltodict`, isso não quer dizer que é performático.

Segue o exemplo de como usar:

```
doc = xmltodict.parse("""
<mydocument has="an attribute">
<and>
<many>elements</many>
<many>more elements</many>
</and>
<plus a="complex">
element as well
</plus>
</mydocument>
""")

print doc['mydocument']['@has']
del doc['mydocument']['and']
unparse(doc)
```

Depois de apagar o nó com `del` você faz um `unparse()` e ele gera o XML!

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um teste aqui com o seu código e os elementos 'extensions' não foram removidos (talvez porque eles não são filhos do root?). De todas as formas, a única diferença que eu notei é que o seu arquivo de origem está no codificado em utf8 e na saída vc codifica em ascii (segundo [a documentação](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) de ElementTree, o padrão do encoding no método write é asc). Tente usar a codificação em utf8 e veja se o resultado é mais condizente.

O código que eu utilizei aqui (e que de fato removeu os itens desejados) é assim:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('input.gpx')

for node in tree.iter():
    for child in node:
        if child.tag == 'extensions':
            node.remove(child)

tree.write('output.gpx', encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: Opa Luiz. Obrigado pela resposta. Consertei a solução que apresentei inicialmente (realmente estava quebrada) mas continuo com o problema inicial. Aproveitei para melhorar a descrição dos problemas. Por favor, edita teu código para indentar o comando de remoção. Tem um <TAB> atrapalhando. Tentei editar mas o sistema proibe edições de 1 caracter.

Comment: Opa, por nada. Ia até voltar a estudar a sua questão, mas acabei de ver que você já resolveu. :)

Answer (score 0):

Gosto do `BeautifulSoup`, geralmente ele atende bem a maioria dos problemas de leitura de XML, mas é importante você ver os outros tipos de parsers que ele tem, caso tenha necessidade saberá como lidar.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Por exemplo, `bs4` consegue usar `lxml` que é super rápido e performático, mas pede dependência do sistema operacional.